# Printing a sequence of random numbers on a line in a text file using awk

Tags: awk, printf

I have text file, names.txt, with every row containing a last name:

```
Smith
Johnson
Morgan
...
...
```

I'd like to add seven random numbers between 0 and 100 to each line to make it look like this:

```
Smith 76 94 56 99 32 21 11
Johnson 54 15.2 19.8 32.66 44.99 22.63 18.99 
Morgan 99 18.6 24.75 99.22 35.18 65.34 54.22
....
....
```

I tried using this command in awk:

```
$ awk '{print $0; for (myvar = 1; myvar <= 7; myvar++) print rand()*100}' names.txt
```

but that gave me

```
Smith
76
94
56
```

etc.

I know I have to use printf, somehow to make it work, and I tried this:

```
$ awk '{printf $0; for (myvar = 1; myvar <= 7; myvar++) printf rand()*100}' names.txt
```

but with that, I get no end-of-lines anywhere. The whole thing is just one line. 
I'll very much appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add *line terminator* at the end of each line

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $0; for (myvar = 1; myvar <= 7; myvar++) \
     printf "%d ", rand()*100; printf "\n"}' names.txt
```

Comment: +1 although it is worth pointing out that the questioner confused print which yields a newline and printf which doesn't. Also noting for the `\n` is a newline for giving to printf.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN { srand(); } 
{ 
  printf("%s", $0); 
  for (i=0;i<7;++i) 
    printf(" %d", 101*rand()); 
  printf("\n");
}'
```

Edit: Changed 100*rand() to 101*rand() since rand() returns a number greater than or equal to zero but less than one (one is not included)